# What is Spec Folder in Orchard CMS solution explorer?

Tags: orchardcms, specifications, orchardcms-1.6

I am new in Orchard CMS and I want to know about the structure code of this CMS.do you know about Spec Folder in Orchard CMS solution explorer?
what is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand these are documentations base on [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) created by [specflow](http://www.specflow.org/specflownew/).thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

It's tests built using Specflow.

See Orchard's [Source Code Organization](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Source-code-organization) page.